# I want to sum bill_amount column where order_id is not same . Actually I want to get due amount

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the eloquent query of Laravel I gave that in below.

Actually, I ignore all `bill_amount`. I want to take only one `bill_amount` per order_id

```
  @php
     $total=App\Billing::where('order_id','!=','order_id')->where('buyer_id',Auth::use

r()->buyer_id)->sum('bill_amount');
         $pay=App\Billing::where('buyer_id',Auth::user()->buyer_id)->sum('payment_amount');
         $due=$total-$pay;
  @endphp
```

Here is the database table red mark I want to get this value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$bill=App\Billing::distinct('bill_amount')->where('order_id','!=','order_id')->where('buyer_id',Auth::user()->buyer_id)->sum('bill_amount')
```

Comment: $bill=App\Billing::distinct('bill_amount')->where('order_id','!=','order_id')->where('buyer_id',Auth::user()->buyer_id)->sum('bill_amount');

Comment: its work  but idea is given by you thank you so much